# How to decide with a School task on Python

Tags: python, cycle

Here is my resulting code.

The task says to try to solve it through `while`.

> The task
> A positive integer from the segment [3;50] is entered from the keyboard.
>
> Find the sum of all positive even numbers strictly less than the given one.

```
n = int(input(f'Введите чило № '))
k = 0
while n>3 and n<50:
  for e in range(3<n<50):
  k = n + e
  print(k)
```

The most difficult thing for me is how to make the code consider what is less than the entered number.
I thought for a couple of hours.

Comment: The inner for loop is just complicating things, you just need to check whether `n` is even before the while loop, and if it isnt then add 1 to it. then in the while loop add n to k and increase it by 2

Comment: Did you even check the correct syntax for `range()`?

Comment: @buran If you are talking about what needs to be put in range 51, and not 50, then yes you are right, I forgot that you need to add +1

Comment: @Sayse +1 to the number? As I understand it, you need to make the code count 3+4+5+6. But how to make it count strictly less.
That is, we are given numbers from 3 to 50, if the number is 40, then the code should do the following 40+39+38+37+36+35+34...., and so on. I started from this right away, maybe that's why the code looks ridiculous

Comment: "... sum of all positive even numbers ..."

Comment: @Sayse I translated the task incorrectly, I still did not understand the question of how to make the count strictly less than the entered number

Comment: No, I mean that `range(3<n<50)` is invalid syntax, i.e. the `3<n<50` part

Comment: @buran Yes, I'm completely confused with this, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have to use `while` this is the answer.

```py
n = int(input(f'Введите чило № '))
n -= n%2
s = 0
while n>0:
  s += n
  n -= 2
```

or

```py
n = int(input(f'Введите чило № '))
i = 2
s = 0
while i<n:
  s += i
  i += 2
```

But the best way is:

```py
n = input(...)
s = sum(range(0,n,2))
```

And after all you can not write `range(3<n<50)`, it does not mean anything in python, the syntax is `range(start,end,step)` for example you should write as follow to go trough 3 to 50:

```py
for i in range(3,50):
  ...
```

or use step to just get even (or odd) numbers in `for` loop:

```py
for i in range(0,50,2):
  ...
```